# Error extension file when use grep to write file

Tags: bash

I have 100 ".txt" files. Each file contains the data such as

```
File name Data
1.txt     BAP1
2.txt     UCHL1
3.txt     ABC1234
```

Now I want to scan content of these files and write to txt file with condition that it contains my input string such as `"BAP1"`. I used below coded but the output files have mistaken such as '1.txt .' I have no idea why the extension file has more dot in last file. Could you help me solve it? I am working in cygwin

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -w 'BAP1' *.txt>"1.txt"
grep -w 'UCHL1' *.txt>"2.txt"
```

Comment: Writing to output files that are inside your input file set is always a bad idea. Put your output files in a different directory, not included in the wildcard.

Comment: Could you suggest a good solution for me? thanks

Comment: I believe I just did.

Comment: BTW, "output files have mistaken such as" is not clear whether it's the names or the content of the output files that are wrong. Please be more careful as to precision of your text.

Comment: ...at this point, I'm almost certain that your actual problem is that your script file has DOS newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `dos2unix` on your script, or otherwise tell your editor to save it as a UNIX text file.

Otherwise, your filenames will have carriage returns (aka `$'\r'`) on the end of their names.

Comment: That mean it will put at first of my scrip

Comment: Huh? No. You can't put it *in* the script, you have to run it *on* the script, **before** the script is run.

Comment: you are right. It returns  1.txt\r'